# unable to create a python function in azure function app

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I was successfully able to create an "HTTP triggered function in Azure" using the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python

I verified running the app using both local environment and the Azure portal. (Deploy the function app project to Azure)

I could not find any instructions on how to deploy the app when I make an update so I again tried:

func azure functionapp publish

I got the message the app was successfully deployed but when I go to Azure portal HttpTrigger is disappeared in the portal. Functions is empty.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: figured out the issue. I needed to run the function from local Function project level and I was running it from the directory that had the function code. Once I ran from local function project level everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

May your function be published to another app instance which you created via `azure-cli` before. According to the section [`Deploy the function app project to Azure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python#deploy-the-function-app-project-to-azure), as below, you can add a parameter `APP_NAME` at the end of publish command to specify the deployment target you want.

```
func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME>
```

I think the `APP_NAME` is default an environment variable stored in some cache while doing app creation.